# What is n_factors in surprise SVD

Tags: recommender-system, matrix-factorisation

The documentation of [Surprise](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html) library is not that great. Can someone please help with details of n_factors in SVD method of Surprise. It simply says:

> n_factors – The number of factors. Default is 100.

A mathematical intution would be really helpful from SVD (singular value decomposition) generic formula wise. For example, where is this value in SVD formula having terms `M = U.sigma.Vt`?

Here's the [link](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/matrix_factorization.html) for SVD method of surprise (for recommender systems).

Answer (score 1):

The number of factors is not something you can typically intuit in a vacuum, the most common way of doing this is by treating it like a hyper-parameter which needs tuning. I would grid search for the best value of n_factors.

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

The factors are the resulting 'entities' created by your singular value decomposition. They provide latent (hidden information) about the items you are comparing from your original variables. The factors are what is used to infer similarity and provide a recommendation.

Comment: What are factors? You answered how to find best value.. but what it is actually?